# How to use php header() to redirect to homepage?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have a link in my `dashboad` page(`http://localhost/dashboard.php`). The link is as following:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">
  <img class="icon mb-n1px" src="assets/icons/sign_out.svg" alt="category icon"> 
  Log Out
</a>
```

In the `logout.php` file, I have the following code:

```
<?php   
    session_unset();
    header("Location: /"); 
  exit();
?>
```

So clicking on that link the user agent is redirected to `http://localhost/`. I want to redirect to `http://localhost` without the trailing slash. My question is

1. Why does `header("Location: ");` not work?
2. Why does `header("Location: ../");` still lead to `http://localhost/`.
3. Why does `header("Location: /../");` doesn't remove the trailing slash?

P.S: I have read the official docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and other SO posts but didn't find any explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use absolute url
`header("Location: http://localhost");`

1. Because you need to specify where do you want to redirect
2. Because `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/` are equal
3. Because there is no upper level then `/`

Comment: Ok, but I mainly want to know about relative urls.

Comment: @user31782 Why are you trying to do this? Trailing slash doesn't matter for root domain/subdomain.

Comment: @user31782 I've added reactions to your questions in my answer

Comment: Yes yes. I am doing this to have better understanding  of php. I thought `header("Location: ")` is different from `header("Location:")` in that, that I am telling php there's an empty space ` ` .  `header("Location:  xyz")` translates to `http://root/xyz` so I don't see why `header("Location:  ")` wouldn't swap `xyz` with ` ` or `NULL`. Probably thats how its defined internally.